# Unity2D Editor Crashes after placing/removing tiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity version 2018.3.6. I have the 2D extra assets. The problem is that every time I try to place down or remove a tile, the editor crashes. After I run Unity again and go into play, there are no crashes.

I need help on this. I tried removing the extra assets but it didn't work. I have spent many hours trying to figure out what's wrong with the system.